# Aliasing str.join in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to alias `str.join` in python3 ?

For example:

```
a=['a','b','c']
j=str.join
''.j(a)
```

but also to be able to do

```
' '.j(a)
```

with the same alias or more generally to be able to use it like:

```
string_here.j(iterable here)
```

Comment: You can define a class to pass the call to `str.join`, is that what you are looking for or do you want to do this with objects that aren't strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite with the syntax you want, but close enough:

```
>>> a=['a','b','c']
>>> j=str.join
>>> j('', a)
'abc'
>>> j(' ', a)
'a b c'
```

`str.join` is an unbound method. To apply it to an object, you need to specify that object as the first argument.

Comment: Dammit, how do you guys type so fast?

Comment: May I just add, to anybody reading this, although this works never actually use this... it looks ugly

Comment: @jamylak When the direct version is obvious, yes. However, in more complex situations where you abstract over stuff by passing functions as arguments, passing unbound methods (though not necessarily `str.join` specifically) does make sense and looks pretty.

Answer (score 2):

> **TL;DR:** Yes, but not in the way you expect.

In your example, you are aliasing an unbound function. What that means simply is that is has no object to apply it on implicitly, so you have to pass on a reference to which object the operations are to be performed on.

This is what the `self` argument in methods is for. Normally you have it automatically passed for you when you use the `. style notation, but here you have to provide it explicitly.

```
>>> list_ = [1, 2, 3]
>>> f = str.join   # aliasing the class method
>>> f(' ', list_)  # passing a reference to s
prints "1 2 3"
>>> f('', list_ )  # flexibility to use any string
```

If you want to be able to just say `f(list_)`, then the `f` function has to be bound. This means you have to know what string you're going to be using in advance. Here's how to do that:

```
>>> str_ = ' '
>>> list_ 
>>> f = str_.join   # aliasing the object method
>>> f(list_)        # no need to pass a reference now
"1 2 3"
```

I hope you understood what I was saying. Python is a great language and has the least gotcha's of any language. I couldn't FGITW my way into the top, but I hope you will like the comprehensive example. If you have any questions, just ask me.